# Fonts appear UGLY in Apache OpenOffice 4 for Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, openoffice, high-dpi

In Apache OpenOffice 4 for Windows, fonts are ugly! While text in Microsoft Word is crisp, in Apache OpenOffice, it is blurred as if "artistic rendering -> translucent glass" special effect was added. Is there a way to improve rendering of OpenOffice fonts?

Here is a sample showing the difference with Times New Roman.

[image]

This is Help->About screen. My screen resolution is 3840x2160.

[image]

This is NOT a question on Linux fonts, so please don't mark as a duplicate of Linux specific question.

Comment: I've attached Help -> About screen. My screen resolution is 3840x2160.

Comment: Even the about dialog box is ugly. But your screen resolution gave me an idea: Maybe Apache OpenOffice is not high-DPI-aware. Unfortunately, someone familiar with the subject must contribute. I don't have a high DPI monitor.

Comment: What is the physical size of your screen?  The issue would likely be different if it is a large screen with ~100 DPI resolution vs. a small screen with ridiculously high pixel density.

Comment: Okay, everything looks perfect on my 1080p 21" screen.

Comment: Tried playing around with Hardware acceleration and anti-aliasing. Not much improvement. https://s22.postimg.org/6ne0cm57l/MSWord_OOWriter_HA_AA.jpg I goess, OpenOffice is not 4K ready yet. Wonder which framework one needs to know to contribute..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot you are using magnification. Check Display settings -> change the size of text. If it is not 100% you would have issues. Microsoft addresses this using some complicated method that can be adopted by OpenOffice... But they would say they don't have enough volunteers to implement it, this is easily addressed by changing scaling and they have more urgent bugs.

Try to change scaling and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following helped.

You may change Compatibility setting of the **SOFFICE.exe** file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe Right click ->
>   Properties -> Change high DPI settings -> High DPI scaling override -
>   check "Override high DPI scaling bahvior. Application"

Windows 7/8

> Right click the file, choose Properties, select the Compatibility tab,
>   and check the box to "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings."
>   Now Open Office is super crisp!